# Dynamically adding a property is not working as expected

Tags: python, lambda

I'm writing a class that at some point adds read/write properties dynamically. My first attempt was

```
class MyGPIO:
    def configure(self):
        gpio_list = [ "a", "b", "c" ]   # only an example here
        input_list = [ "b" ]

        ...
        for gpio in gpio_list:
            getter = lambda obj:  obj.get_gpio(gpio)
            setter = lambda obj,val: obj.set_gpio(gpio, val)

            if gpio in input_list:
                setter = None

            setattr(self.__class__, gpio, property(getter, setter))

    def get_gpio(self, name):
        print "getting %s" % name
        return True

    def set_gpio(self, name, val):
        print "setting %s=%s" % (name, val)
```

but then I ran into the scope problem as described in here https://eev.ee/blog/2011/04/24/gotcha-python-scoping-closures/ , so I modified the code to

```
    def configure(self):
        ...
        for gpio in gpio_list:
            def getset(gpio):
                getter = lambda obj:  obj.get_gpio(gpio)
                setter = lambda obj,val: obj.set_gpio(gpio, val)

                if gpio in input_list:
                    setter = None

                setattr(self.__class__, gpio, property(getter, setter))

            getset(gpio)
```

This seems to work, as you can see from this `ipython` session (`magnet` is in `gpio_list`)

```
In [1]: gpio = MyGPIO()
In [2]: gpio.configure(...)

In [3]: gpio.magnet
getting magnet
Out[3]: True

In [4]: gpio.magnet = False

In [5]: gpio.magnet
Out[5]: False
```

the first time it access the `magnet` read property, the `get_gpio` function is called. However when the write property is accessed, `set_gpio` is ignored (or rather the `setter` lambda in `getset`).

I checked this:

```
In [6]: def setme(obj,x):
   ...:     print "obj=%s,x=%s" % (obj,x)
   ...:     

In [7]: class A(object):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [8]: A.a = property(None, lambda obj,x: setme(obj,x))

In [9]: a = A()

In [10]: a.a = "test"
obj=<__main__.A object at 0x7ff544028790>,x=test
```

here it works as I intended. So why doesn't it work with my example above?

Comment: does you class inherits from object (directly or indirectly)? properties can have strange behaviour with Python2 old-style classes. When you use properties, your classes should inherit from object. https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass

Comment: My class inherits from `traits.api.HasTraits`

Answer (score 2):

Old-style classes (classes which does not explicitly inherit from `object`, directly or not) do not work well with properties.

---

Consider this example code using new-style class:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.random_attribute = "random value"

    @property
    def randattr(self):
        print("getter called")
        return self.random_attribute

    @randattr.setter
    def randattr(self, value):
        print("setter called")
        self.random_attribute = value

t = Test()
print(t.randattr)
t.randattr = "an other value"
print(t.randattr)
```

prints:

```
getter called
random value
setter called
getter called
an other value
```

It works as expected:

- it calls the getter when we access the value
- it calls the setter when we set the value
- the value set is correclty accessed

---

now consider the exact same code except that the class does not inherit from object:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.random_attribute = "random value"

    @property
    def randattr(self):
        print("getter called")
        return self.random_attribute

    @randattr.setter
    def randattr(self, value):
        print("setter called")
        self.random_attribute = value

t = Test()
print(t.randattr)
t.randattr = "an other value"
print(t.randattr)
```

prints:

```
getter called
random value
an other value
```

It does not work:

- the getter is called when we access the value
- the setter is not called when we set the value, this means that the value actually erase the property and this will no more work as intended.
- the getter is no more called when we access the value again.

---

The `HasTraits` class inherits from `CHasTraits` which comes from a binary module. So it is difficult to conclude anything.

---

This is one of the problems caused by old-style classes, but not the only one.
In general, in Python 2.7 it is a good practice to always explicitely inherit from object (unless you inherit from a class which inherits from object).

Comment: Because of the same behaviour with old-style classes, I'd presume that `traits` uses the old-style class. The strange thing is that when I use the decorators then it works without a problem).

Answer (score 1):

As @Tryph pointed out in the comments in Python2 this is an issue between old style and new style classes. The difference in a new-style class is that your class muss inherit from `object`.

## script1.py - old style class

```
class MyGPIO(object):
    def configure(self):
        gpio_list = [ "magnet" ,]   # only an example here
        input_list = [ "b" ]
        for gpio in gpio_list:
            def getset(gpio):
                getter = lambda obj:  obj.get_gpio(gpio)
                setter = lambda obj,val: obj.set_gpio(gpio, val)

                if gpio in input_list:
                    setter = None

                setattr(self.__class__, gpio, property(getter, setter))

            getset(gpio)

    def get_gpio(self, name):
        print "getting %s" % name
        return True

    def set_gpio(self, name, val):
        print "setting %s=%s" % (name, val)
gpio = MyGPIO()
gpio.configure()
gpio.magnet
gpio.magnet = False
```

## output 1

```
getting magnet
```

## script2.py - new style class (inheriting from `object`)

```
class MyGPIO(object):
    def configure(self):
        gpio_list = [ "magnet" ,]   # only an example here
        input_list = [ "b" ]
        for gpio in gpio_list:
            def getset(gpio):
                getter = lambda obj:  obj.get_gpio(gpio)
                setter = lambda obj,val: obj.set_gpio(gpio, val)

                if gpio in input_list:
                    setter = None

                setattr(self.__class__, gpio, property(getter, setter))

            getset(gpio)

    def get_gpio(self, name):
        print "getting %s" % name
        return True

    def set_gpio(self, name, val):
        print "setting %s=%s" % (name, val)
gpio = MyGPIO()
gpio.configure()
gpio.magnet
gpio.magnet = False
```

## output 2

```
getting magnet
setting magnet=False
```

For more information on old vs. new style classes and their impact on descriptors ( essentially what you are doing) have a look at https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that way `traits` generate its classes, the `property` type is not that well supported. `traits` does it's own "magic" and this might be getting in the way of the `property` type. Perhaps that's the reason why the decorators work.